# Ativar função Jquery ao ter x caracteres

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Muito bom dia!

Tenho um formulário com apenas um input:

```
    <input type="number" name="codigo" class="form-control" style="margin-left: 2%" autofocus id='codigo'>
```

E preciso que quando o input atinja 6 caracteres ele automaticamente finalize o formulário e mande as informações para a página que está no `action=''`, ou "emule" o evento do botão enter, ou ative o `<button type="submit">` é possível fazer uma coisa dessas? É necessário que não haja necessidade da ação humana de apertar o botão.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixei duas opções de códigos em *JQuery*, quando você atingir 6 ou mais caracteres será chamada a ação do botão ou submeter o formulário.

**Observação:** Você não deu detalhes dos nomes dos seus controles, altere para os nomes corretos.

**1º solução:** Chamamos o clique do seu botão

```
$('#inputTexto').on('keyup', function() { 
    if ($(this).val().length >= 6) {
        // Acionamos o clique do seu botão
        $('#btnAcaoEnter').click();
    }
});
```

**2º solução:** Submetemos o formulário para o servidor

```
$('#inputTexto').on('keyup', function() { 
    if ($(this).val().length >= 6) {
        // Submetemos o fomulário
        $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

Altere o `#inputTexto` para o `id` do seu input que o usuário digitará os 6 caracteres.

Altere o `#btnAcaoEnter` para o `id`do seu botão que queira que seja acionada a função de clique quando o input de texto atingir 6 ou mais caracteres.

Comment: Não seria melhor usar `$('form').submit()` ao invés de simular o click no botão?

Comment: Eu fiz o clique do botão por pedido na pergunta, mas é uma boa ideia. Vou adicionar na resposta essa outra solução. Obrigado!!

Comment: Perguntei por que nem sempre o autor da pergunta sabe exatamente o que precisa :)

Comment: Verdade........

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito e resolveu o meu problema!